# how to add pause and play to a scroll plugin

Tags: jquery

I've this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/TC5Zf/
how can I pause the animation on `mouseenter` and resume it on `mouseout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use stop()

http://jsfiddle.net/TC5Zf/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var ob = $('.scrollingtext');
        var tw = ob.width();
        var ww = ob.parent().width();
        ob.css({ left: -tw });

    $('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() {
        var oba = $(this);
        var twa = ob.width();
        var wwa = ob.parent().width();

        oba.animate({ left: wwa }, 50000, 'linear', function() {
            oba.trigger('marquee');
        });
    }).trigger('marquee');

        $(".scrollingtext").mouseout(function(){
           $(".scrollingtext").trigger('marquee'); 
        });
        $(".scrollingtext").mouseover(function(){
           $(".scrollingtext").stop(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the blog entry by the original author of that code:
[Max Vergelli: how to pause and resume scrolling of a marquee](http://maxvergelli.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/scrolling-text-with-jquery-how-to-pause-or-resume-scrolling-on-mouseover-mouseout-control-velocity-and-direction/)

Here's a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/TC5Zf/10/